# If select option value is equal to (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery that performs come validation on `POST`

```
 (function($) {
        $( document ).ready(function() {
             jQuery('#post').submit(function() {
                    if ($("#_sku").val() == '') {
                        alert("Please enter a valid GTIN");
                        $('#ajax-loading').hide();
                        $('#publish').removeClass('button-primary-disabled');
                        $('#_sku').focus();
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
            });
        });
    }(jQuery));
```

This currently works well, however I need to add another condition to the `if statement`. I need to apply the rule only when the value of the following select box is eqaul to "simple"

```
<select id="product-type" name="product-type">
<optgroup label="Product Type">
<option value="simple"  selected='selected'>Simple product</option>
<option value="grouped" >Grouped product</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

I have tried this in my if statement:

```
if ($("#_sku").val() == '' && $("#_product-type").val() == 'simple') {
```

But this does not apply the rules within the if statement when product-type is equal to "simple". Could anyone suggest what the issue is here?

Comment: you added an  underscore in the jquery code _product-type, but in html there is no underscore in the Id

Comment: use $("#product-type").val()

Comment: I was going to say the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you. You can also use === instead of == which is more faster and accurate. Because === doesn't make any cast

```
if ($("#_sku").val() == '' && $("#product-type").val() == 'simple')
```